# What is the difference between region activation and region RequestNavigate?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism, region

I use one region with 2 views. I have a `ComboBox` that let the user to select view in region.

I have 2 questions:

First question is what is the difference between:

```
_regionManager.Regions.Add("MyRegion")
_regionManager.Regions["MyRegion"].Add(container.Resolve<OneView>())
_regionManager.Regions["MyRegion"].Add(container.Resolve<SecondView>())
```

To:

```
_regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("MyRegion", () => container.Resolve<OneView>());
_regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("MyRegion", () => container.Resolve<SecondView>());
```

and my second question is what is the difference between:

```
_regionManager.Regions["MyRegion"].ActiveViews.ForEach(view => _region.Deactivate(view));
_regionManager.Regions["MyRegion"].Activate(container.Resolve<SecondView>());
```

To:

```
_regionManager.Regions["MyRegion"].RequestNavigate(new Uri("SecondView", UriKind.Relative));
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference on the first comparison you mentioned would be that ***RegisterViewWithRegion()*** method activates the registered **View** at the end of the process while the first implementation only adds the **Views**. 
This ***RegisterViewWithRegion()*** approach is called ***View Discovery***. You may find a related answer in the following post made by you yesterday:

- [What is the difference between register a region to adding a region in prism?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814911/what-is-the-difference-between-register-a-region-to-adding-a-region-in-prism/21832111#21832111)

Helpful information on **MSDN Prism Guide**:

- [Composing the User Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921098%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx#sec24)

For the second comparison, it would depend on the **Region** type. The First implementation would only leave the **SecondView** activated. However, ***RequestNavigate()*** may not deactivate the previous **View** if the **Region** is an ***ItemsControl*** type. An ***ItemsControl* Region** lets you append many **Views** so you can have more than one active **View**.

If this is the case, the **SecondView** would appear below the previously active **View** in the **Region**. But if you don't want this behavior you have 2 options:

1. Make the **Region** type as a ***ContentControl***, so only one View would be displayed at a time;
2. Deactivate the previous **View** inside the ***OnNavigatedFrom()*** method. You would need to make the previous **View** inherits from **INavigationAware**.

Helpful information about **RequestNavigate()** and **Navigation** on **MSDN Prism Guide**:

- [View-Based Navigation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430861%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx#sec6)

I hope this helps, Regards.